# Glide load remote svg lost color, how to fix it?

Tags: android, svg, android-glide

When I use Glide load remote svg, it doesn't display correctly, the background color is lost, but it displays correctly in Chrome.

This is correct

[image: normal]

But I load and display not correctly

[image: error]

The black background is set by me so that white text can be seen

This is my source code and svg url

```
        Glide.with(this)
            .`as`(PictureDrawable::class.java)
            .listener(SvgSoftwareLayerSetter())
            .load("https://api.edns.domains/metadata/0x53a0018f919bde9C254bda697966C5f448ffDDcB/30610703517456202125772346661883251373457451536551224931705160096554106665587/image.svg")
            .into(binding.iv1)

public class SvgDecoder implements ResourceDecoder<InputStream, SVG> {

  @Override
  public boolean handles(@NonNull InputStream source, @NonNull Options options) {
    return true;
  }

  public Resource<SVG> decode(
      @NonNull InputStream source, int width, int height, @NonNull Options options)
      throws IOException {
    try {
      SVG svg = SVG.getFromInputStream(source);
      return new SimpleResource<>(svg);
    } catch (SVGParseException ex) {
      throw new IOException("Cannot load SVG from stream", ex);
    }
  }
}

public class SvgDrawableTranscoder implements ResourceTranscoder<SVG, PictureDrawable> {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Resource<PictureDrawable> transcode(@NonNull Resource<SVG> toTranscode, @NonNull Options options) {
        SVG svg = toTranscode.get();
        Picture picture = svg.renderToPicture();
        PictureDrawable drawable = new PictureDrawable(picture);
        return new SimpleResource<>(drawable);
    }
}

@GlideModule
public class SvgModule extends AppGlideModule {
  @Override
  public void registerComponents(
      @NonNull Context context, @NonNull Glide glide, @NonNull Registry registry) {
    registry
        .register(SVG.class, PictureDrawable.class, new SvgDrawableTranscoder())
        .append(InputStream.class, SVG.class, new SvgDecoder());
  }

  // Disable manifest parsing to avoid adding similar modules twice.
  @Override
  public boolean isManifestParsingEnabled() {
    return false;
  }
}

public class SvgSoftwareLayerSetter implements RequestListener<PictureDrawable> {

    @Override
    public boolean onLoadFailed(GlideException e, Object model, Target<PictureDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
        ImageView view = ((ImageViewTarget<?>) target).getView();
        view.setLayerType(ImageView.LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onResourceReady(PictureDrawable resource, Object model, Target<PictureDrawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
        ImageView view = ((ImageViewTarget<?>) target).getView();
        view.setLayerType(ImageView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        return false;
    }
}
```

How to fix it?????????

Comment: Please include the source code. You are now saying _"My car doesn't run"_, and showing us a picture of your car.

Comment: It looks like Glide doesn't support SVG out of the box, what other libraries are you using to load SVG?

Comment: I re-edited my question